# clicking "add cloud" under configuration in jenkins-mesos plugin is unresponsive

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

this is an almost vanilla jenkins running on top of mesos
Jenkins version is 2.128
When I inspected the running page, I found this in the network->response tab of the debugger.

this looks like a missing dependency, but everything seems to be where it should be. 
Googling for the error itself was unfruitful.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html><html><head resURL="/static/cbb02ec1" data-rooturl="" data-resurl="/static/cbb02ec1">


    <title>Jenkins [Jenkins]</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/cbb02ec1/css/layout-common.css" type="text/css" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/cbb02ec1/css/style.css" type="text/css" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/cbb02ec1/css/color.css" type="text/css" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/cbb02ec1/css/responsive-grid.css" type="text/css" /><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/cbb02ec1/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" /><link color="black" rel="mask-icon" href="/images/mask-icon.svg" /><script>var isRunAsTest=false; var rootURL=""; var resURL="/static/cbb02ec1";</script><script src="/static/cbb02ec1/scripts/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/static/cbb02ec1/scripts/behavior.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/static/cbb02ec1/scripts/yui/yahoo/yahoo-min.js"></script><script src="/static/cbb02ec1/scripts/yui/dom/dom-min.js"></script><script src="/static/cbb02ec1/scripts/yui/event/event-min.js"></script><script src="/static/cbb02ec1/scripts/yui/animation/animation-min.js"></script><script src="/static/cbb02ec1/scripts/yui/dragdrop/dragdrop-min.js"></script><script src="/static/cbb02ec1/scripts/yui/container/container-min.js"></script><script src="/static/cbb02ec1/scripts/yui/connection/connection-min.js"></script><script src="/static/cbb02ec1/scripts/yui/datasource/datasource-min.js"></script><script src="/static/cbb02ec1/scripts/yui/autocomplete/autocomplete-min.js"></script><script src="/static/cbb02ec1/scripts/yui/menu/menu-min.js"></script><script src="/static/cbb02ec1/scripts/yui/element/element-min.js"></script><script src="/static/cbb02ec1/scripts/yui/button/button-min.js"></script><script src="/static/cbb02ec1/scripts/yui/storage/storage-min.js"></script><script src="/static/cbb02ec1/scripts/hudson-behavior.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/static/cbb02ec1/scripts/sortable.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script>crumb.init("Jenkins-Crumb", "d507ce4168e53b5533961e1e6c8a7d9c");</script><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/cbb02ec1/scripts/yui/container/assets/container.css" type="text/css" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/cbb02ec1/scripts/yui/assets/skins/sam/skin.css" type="text/css" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/cbb02ec1/scripts/yui/container/assets/skins/sam/container.css" type="text/css" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/cbb02ec1/scripts/yui/button/assets/skins/sam/button.css" type="text/css" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/cbb02ec1/scripts/yui/menu/assets/skins/sam/menu.css" type="text/css" /><link rel="search" href="/opensearch.xml" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Jenkins" /><meta name="ROBOTS" content="INDEX,NOFOLLOW" /><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /><script>var Q=jQuery.noConflict()</script><script src="/static/cbb02ec1/jsbundles/page-init.js" type="text/javascript"></script></head><body data-model-type="hudson.model.Hudson" id="jenkins" class="yui-skin-sam two-column jenkins-2.128" data-version="2.128"><a href="#skip2content" class="skiplink">Skip to content</a><div id="page-head"><div id="header"><div class="logo"><a id="jenkins-home-link" href="/"><img src="/static/cbb02ec1/images/headshot.png" alt="title" id="jenkins-head-icon" /><img src="/static/cbb02ec1/images/title.png" alt="title" width="139" id="jenkins-name-icon" height="34" /></a></div><div class="login"> </div><div class="searchbox hidden-xs"><form method="get" name="search" action="/search/" style="position:relative;" class="no-json"><div id="search-box-minWidth"></div><div id="search-box-sizer"></div><div id="searchform"><input name="q" placeholder="search" id="search-box" class="has-default-text" /> <a href="https://jenkins.io/redirect/search-box"><img src="/static/cbb02ec1/images/16x16/help.png" style="width: 16px; height: 16px; " class="icon-help icon-sm" /></a><div id="search-box-completion"></div><script>createSearchBox("/search/");</script></div></form></div></div><div id="breadcrumbBar"><tr id="top-nav"><td id="left-top-nav" colspan="2"><div class="top-sticker noedge"><div class="top-sticker-inner"><div id="right-top-nav"></div><ul id="breadcrumbs"><li class="item"><a href="/" class="model-link inside">Jenkins</a></li><li href="/" class="children"></li></ul><div id="breadcrumb-menu-target"></div></div></div></td></tr></div></div><div id="page-body" class="clear"><div id="side-panel"><div class="task"><a href="https://jenkins.io/" class="task-icon-link"><img src="/static/cbb02ec1/images/24x24/next.png" style="width: 24px; height: 24px; width: 24px; height: 24px; margin: 2px;" class="icon-next icon-md" /></a> <a href="https://jenkins.io/" class="task-link">Jenkins project</a></div><div class="task"><a href="https://jenkins.io/redirect/report-an-issue" class="task-icon-link"><img src="/static/cbb02ec1/images/24x24/gear2.png" style="width: 24px; height: 24px; width: 24px; height: 24px; margin: 2px;" class="icon-gear2 icon-md" /></a> <a href="https://jenkins.io/redirect/report-an-issue" class="task-link">Bug tracker</a></div><div class="task"><a href="https://jenkins.io/redirect/mailing-lists" class="task-icon-link"><img src="/static/cbb02ec1/images/24x24/search.png" style="width: 24px; height: 24px; width: 24px; height: 24px; margin: 2px;" class="icon-search icon-md" /></a> <a href="https://jenkins.io/redirect/mailing-lists" class="task-link">Mailing Lists</a></div><div class="task"><a href="https://twitter.com/jenkinsci" class="task-icon-link"><img src="/static/cbb02ec1/images/24x24/user.png" style="width: 24px; height: 24px; width: 24px; height: 24px; margin: 2px;" class="icon-user icon-md" /></a> <a href="https://twitter.com/jenkinsci" class="task-link">Twitter: @jenkinsci</a></div></div><div id="main-panel"><a name="skip2content"></a><h1 style="text-align: center"><img src="/static/cbb02ec1/images/rage.png" width="154" height="179" /><span style="font-size:50px"> Oops!</span></h1><div id="error-description"><p>A problem occurred while processing the request.
        Please check <a href="https://jenkins.io/redirect/issue-tracker">our bug tracker</a> to see if a similar problem has already been reported.
        If it is already reported, please vote and put a comment on it to let us gauge the impact of the problem.
        If you think this is a new issue, please file a new issue.
        When you file an issue, make sure to add the entire stack trace, along with the version of Jenkins and relevant plugins.
        <a href="https://jenkins.io/redirect/users-mailing-list">The users list</a> might be also useful in understanding what has happened.</p><h2>Stack trace</h2><pre style="margin:2em; clear:both">org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-2.128.jar!/lib/form/hetero-list.jelly:131:100: &lt;st:include> com/codahale/metrics/Timer$Context
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.handleException(TagScript.java:745)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:289)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.TagSupport.invokeBody(TagSupport.java:161)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.OtherwiseTag.doTag(OtherwiseTag.java:41)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.TagSupport.invokeBody(TagSupport.java:161)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.ChooseTag.doTag(ChooseTag.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:120)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:99)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:63)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:53)
    at hudson.widgets.RenderOnDemandClosure$1.generateResponse(RenderOnDemandClosure.java:123)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.HttpResponseRenderer$Default.handleHttpResponse(HttpResponseRenderer.java:124)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.HttpResponseRenderer$Default.generateResponse(HttpResponseRenderer.java:69)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.renderResponse(Function.java:136)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:119)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$JavaScriptProxyMethodDispatcher.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:473)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$10.dispatch(MetaClass.java:374)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:782)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:199)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1655)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.reverse_proxy_auth.ReverseProxySecurityRealm$1.doFilter(ReverseProxySecurityRealm.java:559)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1317)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1219)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService.lambda$scheduleNext$0(BoundedExecutorService.java:80)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/codahale/metrics/Timer$Context
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.ClassDescriptor.findMethods(ClassDescriptor.java:149)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.ClassDescriptor.&lt;init>(ClassDescriptor.java:85)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.lang.KlassNavigator$1.getFunctions(KlassNavigator.java:216)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.lang.KlassNavigator$1.getFunctions(KlassNavigator.java:141)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.lang.Klass.getFunctions(Klass.java:98)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.KlassDescriptor.&lt;init>(KlassDescriptor.java:27)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass.buildDispatchers(MetaClass.java:105)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass.&lt;init>(MetaClass.java:93)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.WebApp.getMetaClass(WebApp.java:204)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.GroovyFacet.createRequestDispatcher(GroovyFacet.java:109)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.getView(RequestImpl.java:257)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.getView(RequestImpl.java:252)
    at hudson.model.Descriptor.getHelpFile(Descriptor.java:750)
    at hudson.model.Descriptor.getHelpFile(Descriptor.java:732)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor93.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.util.introspection.UberspectImpl$VelMethodImpl.invoke(UberspectImpl.java:258)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTMethod.execute(ASTMethod.java:104)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTReference.execute(ASTReference.java:83)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTReference.value(ASTReference.java:57)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTReferenceExpression.value(ASTReferenceExpression.java:51)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.ExpressionImpl.evaluate(ExpressionImpl.java:80)
    at hudson.ExpressionFactory2$JexlExpression.evaluate(ExpressionFactory2.java:74)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$3.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:134)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$1.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:98)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:120)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyViewScript.run(JellyViewScript.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.IncludeTag.doTag(IncludeTag.java:147)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
    ... 101 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.codahale.metrics.Timer$Context
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1374)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1327)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1080)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 138 more
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to evaluate the template closure
    at hudson.widgets.RenderOnDemandClosure$1.generateResponse(RenderOnDemandClosure.java:126)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.HttpResponseRenderer$Default.handleHttpResponse(HttpResponseRenderer.java:124)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.HttpResponseRenderer$Default.generateResponse(HttpResponseRenderer.java:69)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.renderResponse(Function.java:136)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:119)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$JavaScriptProxyMethodDispatcher.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:473)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$10.dispatch(MetaClass.java:374)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:782)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:199)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1655)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.reverse_proxy_auth.ReverseProxySecurityRealm$1.doFilter(ReverseProxySecurityRealm.java:559)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1317)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1219)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService.lambda$scheduleNext$0(BoundedExecutorService.java:80)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
</pre></div></div></div><footer><div class="container-fluid"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-6" id="footer"></div><div class="col-md-18"><span class="page_generated">Page generated: Jun 21, 2018 1:59:49 PM GMT</span><span class="rest_api"><a href="api/">REST API</a></span><span class="jenkins_ver"><a href="https://jenkins.io/">Jenkins ver. 2.128</a></span></div></div></div></footer></body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and downgrade to latest LTS version but that didn't resolve.
I installed the Jenkins [Metrics Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Metrics+Plugin) which resolved the issue as it has the dependency needed by Mesos Plugin.